# How to pass back some text from client side to server side using Express 4.0?

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, express

There are similar SO questions, but I could not find a precise answer to this issue.

I need to push back some text from the client side to the server side from time to time. The user side does not expect an answer from the server side. I though I would use POST as following:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('POST', MY_URL, true);
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html;charset=utf-8');
request.send(myMsg);
```

From Chrome, I can see that the header and payload are correct. The status is 200 OK.

On the server side, I try to retrieve the body content as following:

```
function myFunction(req, res) {

    console.log("Reached myFunction, reqBody is: '" + req.body + "'");
    res.end();

}
```

But I get:

```
Reached myFunction, reqBody is: 'undefined'
```

What am I doing wrong? Should I use `'application/json; charset=utf-8'` with a JSON instead?

**Update**

I have been doing some more research and the `req` object on the server side does not have a `body` property. However, the `headers` is fine.

I initiate my application with the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
...
self.app = express();
...
self.app.use(bodyParser());
self.app.use(cookieParser());
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the body-parser middleware?

Comment: Yes: self.app.use(bodyParser());

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `body-parser` middleware, it's important that the content type matches.  In this case, you've specified `text/html`, so you should use the [`bodyParser.text()`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparsertextoptions) middleware.  In addition, you need to specify `text/html` as the `type`.  So a full example would look like:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.text({
    type: "text/html"
}));

app.post("/test", function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end();
});

app.listen(3000);
```

You could also use a wildcard, such as `type: "text/*"` for the options to `bodyParser.text()`.

When I ran this using your example, I see "hi" output to the console when I hit /test.

Comment: You were right. I also had to record my routes AFTER calls to app.use(..)

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

this might help.